# IncompatibleClassChangeError when running spark from (spring) servlet

Tags: spring, servlets, apache-spark

When running a simple spark job from a (spring) web app, I get an `IncompatibleClassChangeError`. It is probably due to some incompatible dependencies, but I cannot find which.

To put it simply, [this is the issue](https://github.com/julien-diener/sparkwebapp/issues/1) with exception stack.

Here is [the failing code](https://github.com/julien-diener/sparkwebapp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/proto/sparkwebapp/SparkUpper.java#L67):

```
// file conversion with spark
// --------------------------
JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = sparkContext.textFile(inputFile).cache();

Function fct = new Function<String,String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(String line) throws Exception {
        return line.toUpperCase();
    }
};
JavaRDD<Strineg> outputRdd = inputRdd.map(fct); // *** fail ***

outputRdd.saveAsTextFile(outputDir);
```

And it is called from [a simple spring servlet](https://github.com/julien-diener/sparkwebapp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/proto/sparkwebapp/Service.java):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/upper")
public @ResponseBody boolean upper(@RequestParam(required = true) String inputFile,
                                   @RequestParam(required = true) String outputDir,
                                   @RequestParam(required = false) String master,
                                   @RequestParam(required = false) String namenode) {
    if(master==null) master = "local";
    SparkUpper.upper(inputFile, outputDir, master, namenode);

    return true;
}
```

And here is [the (maven) dependencies](https://github.com/julien-diener/sparkwebapp/blob/master/pom.xml):

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- spring -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- spark & hadoop -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The strange thing is that is basically do the same, with same spark dependencies but called from a servlet, as in [this project](https://github.com/julien-diener/spark-csvconverter) that works fine.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sticks out to me is that you have `hadoop-core:1.2.1` with `hadoop-client:2.5.2`.  These are conflicting versions.  Also, in your other project you are using spark 1.1.0 vs 1.2.1.

Comment: I tried with spark 1.2.1 in my other project with no problem. Then I've basically taken the last hadoop client and the core of the same version of hadoop I am using. Once again it works without spring...

Comment: Does `mvn dependency:tree` show conflicts? And how are they resolved my Maven?

Comment: I tried that but there are a lot of conflicts... Way too many to check each of them, or I need an efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to investigate dependency conflict using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` which showed too many of them, I found a practical solution:

Replace the maven dependencies included in the war by the `spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar` that I used to run my [previous non-spring code](https://github.com/julien-diener/spark-csvconverter).

In practice:

1. install the spark-assembly jar in local maven:

   `mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=$SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar \
    -DgroupId=org.apache.spark -DartifactId=spark-assembly-jar \
    -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar`
2. Include it in the maven dependencies:

   `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-assembly-jar</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>`
3. remove the spark and hadoop jar from the war by adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to `spark-core`, `hadoop-core` and `hadoop-client`.

What I understand is that the conflict may be between the spark and hadoop dependencies, and not from spark/hadoop vs spring. But this is bypassed by using the spark-assembly jar that contains everything that has been build together.

It is not a very satisfying solution, and it add a 140MB jar dependency, but it works. It would be better to find the suitable set of spark/hadoop dependencies that actually work with each others.

Also, I could look for a way to include this `spark-assembly` jar in the classpath of the servlet container instead of into the war.